# ARM template conditional nested resources without template linking

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a conditional resource template. The devel environment is not as beefy as the production environment and I've been successful in doing this for the most part. However, I can't seem to get nested resources right.

Here's a snippet from my ARM template:

```
"webApp-resources": "[variables(concat('webApp-', parameters('env'), '-resources'))]",
"webApp-dev-resources": [],
"webApp-prod-resources": [
  {
    "name": "staging",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webApp-name'))]"
    ]
  }
],
```

The idea is simple, the resources variable is composed using the `env` parameter. The `env` parameter can be either `dev` or `prod` and while this works, I get the following error when I try to deploy this template.

```
{
  "name": "[variables('webApp-name')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  ...
  "resources": "[variables('webApp-resources')]" // <- culprit!
},
```

> The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "[variables('webApp-resources')]" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Schema.TemplateResource[]'. Path 'properties.template.resources[1].resources', line 195, position 64.'

I've also tried moving the resource into a variable and referencing the variable in a similar conditional manner, very similar to how we would do nested template linking but without the template linking.

```
resources: [
  "[variables('webApp-resource')]" // <- this doesn't work!
]
```

This resulted in a similar error but different error if I recalled correctly.

*From this I've concluded that ARM template syntax is not simply find and replace which I think is bad because it does make it harder to reason about what works and what doesn't. Because if it was, this would have resulted in a valid template that would work. Which I've verified by pasting the correct value into the resources section.*

Has anyone had similar problems, how did you work around the issue?

Comment: actually, I'm not even sure if I'm answering the right question, I don't exactly understand your problem, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Deployment slots are only supported by the standard and up App Service Plans, the devel environment doesn't need deployment slots so I opted to not use them. However, I now have a deployment template that needs to vary depending on which environment it is deployed into. This I've managed to do OK but I haven't been able to add the deployment slot "staging" so that this slot only exists in the *prod* environment. *dev* environment is using basic tier but *prod* is using standard tier. The errors in my question portrays to various (IMAO) straightforward attempts at making this happen.

Comment: are you attempting to use `variable` instead of a `resource`? I'm pretty sure you can't do that, but you can create slots conditionally

Comment: @4c74356b41 I did try to use a variable as a resource, under the assumption that ARM templates simply do JSON substitutions but that didn't work. I dunno why.

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up with atomic ARM templates (eg. serviceplan, appservice, deploymentslot etc.) and couple of PowerShell modules and scripts that do the magic.

Comment: @MichalCumpl it bothers me that the syntax isn't universal. Why does MSFT have to complicate things... what is _atomic_ ARM templates. I already have a mishmash of scripts to do the plumping, don't mind doing more with PowerShell, though ARM deployments are preferable.

Comment: With atomic templates I mean smallest ARM templates that can be later combined programmatically with New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this without multiple template files, but not without using nested deployments.  So depending on what you're trying to avoid, try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "env": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [ "dev", "prod" ]
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "resourceArray": "[variables(concat('resources', parameters('env')))]",
    "resourcesprod": [
        {
          "name": "as",
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [],
          "properties": {
          }
        }
      ],
    "resourcesdev": []
  },
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "nest",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": "[variables('resourceArray')]"
          },
          "parameters": {
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I basically did this but I tried to slot the nested template resources directly into the resources array. Is it necessary to specify the `$schema` and `contentVersion` multiple times? I want to keep the file small and compact, if possible.

Comment: Is there anything in particular one should be aware of with regards to nested deployments. I noted that they appear as separate deployments in the resource group. Any gotchas you know of?

Comment: I edited the code in the original answer - you can make it a bit smaller, schema validation will throw some warnings but it should work fine.  re: gotchas - nothing I can think of related to your OP.